# Stopping and Proceeding a For Loop

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop

I have a problem on looping. This is a game of Whack the Mole. First, there is a for loop that is in charge of generating different hole positions for my moles. I want it so that the loop will (1) Generate a number (2) Stop the generating (3) Based on the number that was just generated, run a function for it. Once done running the function, then (4)Start the second round of generating another number......and it goes on for 9 rounds. I have my code here.

```
var molePosX:Array = [166.90, 494.8, 810.7];
var molePosY:Array = [282.55, 512.45, 730.35];
var moleInUse:Boolean = false;

if (moleInUse == false){
for(var i:uint = 1; i<10; i++){
var randomHole:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1; //Generate 10 number
trace(randomHole);
}
}


switch (randomHole){
case 1: trace("1");
moleRun(molePosX[0],molePosY[0]);
break;
case 2: trace("2");
moleRun(molePosX[1],molePosY[0]);
break;
case 3: trace("3");
moleRun(molePosX[2],molePosY[0]);
break;
case 4: trace("4");
moleRun(molePosX[0],molePosY[1]);
break;
case 5: trace("5");
moleRun(molePosX[1],molePosY[1]);
break;
case 6: trace("6");
moleRun(molePosX[2],molePosY[1]);
break;
case 7: trace("7");
moleRun(molePosX[0],molePosY[2]);
break;
case 8: trace("8");
moleRun(molePosX[1],molePosY[2]);
break;
case 9: trace("9");
moleRun(molePosX[2],molePosY[2]);
break;
case 10: trace("10");
break;
}



function moleRun(xPos:Number,yPos:Number){
    moleInUse = true;
    var mole2:Mole = new Mole();
    mole2.x = xPos;
    mole2.y = yPos;
    addChild(mole2);
    moleInUse = false;
}
```

Thank you ver much!!!

Comment: Well, is it possible to stop the loop and continue it on?

Answer (score 0):

You should start the loop with the last broken iteration number. It would be easy to write a separate function for (1) generating the random number. Like:

```
 // this is a global or instance variable
 var iter:uint = 1;
 // funcation to generate the random number and updating the value of iteration
 function taskNumber1() {
    for(var i:uint = iter; i<10; i++) {
      var randomHole:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1; //Generate 10 number
      iter = i;
      break;
   }
   return randomHole;
}
```

Try it.

Comment: Thank you very much but I don't quite get it? Where am I supposed to place this? Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not really an answer, but just a suggestion for removing that long switch statement. I added this as an answer as comments don't really format code well...

It looks like you want it to be:

```
Where index/randomHole = xPos, yPos
1 = 0, 0
2 = 1, 0
3 = 2, 0
4 = 0, 1
5 = 1, 1
6 = 2, 1
7 = 0, 2
8 = 1, 2
9 = 2, 2
```

You can calculate it out rather then having a long switch statement instead:

```
x = (index - 1) % 3;
y = Math.floor((index - 1) / 3.0);
```

or to keep with your variable names:

```
var xPosIndex:int = (randomHole - 1) % 3;
var yPosIndex:int = Math.floor((randomHole - 1) / 3);
moleRun(molePosX[xPosIndex],molePosY[yPosIndex]);
```

The hardcoded 3 is the row length, since it looks like each row has 3 values in it (x goes from 0 to 2). An index/randomHole value of 10 would yield x = 0, y = 3 (starting another "row")